# Spring version migration

Tags: java, spring, xsd, version

I have an application which uses spring 3.2.8.RELEASE and spring security 3.2.3.RELEASE. I wanted to update versions to be more on time. I have changed spring to 4.1.6.RELEASE and security 4.0.1.RELEASE. After that in my context.xml it was obvious to change namespaces so I did it for example

`http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd` to `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd`

Now when I want to log into my app I have an 403 error - unauthorized.
But in context.xml I think configuration is correct

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/user/authenticate" access="permitAll"/>
```

full security config in context.xml

```
<security:http
        realm="Protected API"
        use-expressions="true"
        auto-config="false"
        create-session="always"
        entry-point-ref="unauthorizedEntryPoint"
        authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/user/authenticate" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url method="GET" pattern="/rest/news/**" access="hasRole('user')" />
    <security:intercept-url method="PUT" pattern="/rest/news/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />
    <security:intercept-url method="POST" pattern="/rest/news/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />
    <security:intercept-url method="DELETE" pattern="/rest/news/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />
<security:logout  delete-cookies="SESSIONID" logout-success-url="/" invalidate-session="true"/>
    </security:http>
```

I cant find any information how to fix this problem - any ideas what else changes do I have to make?

By the way. Front end is angular and `unauthorizedEntryPoint` is not fired.

Comment: is your request going to ```authenticationTokenProcessingFilter```, Do you actually authenticate in this class?

Comment: No filter is not fired.